# Graph-traversal with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm wondering how to write a graph traversal algorithm using promises (I'm using JavaScript/Bluebird). Each node's definition is in a database, fetching each node is asynchronous.

Let's consider a breadth-first search where we are given the root node and each node has a reference to its children. We need to fetch the root node's children and enqueue them to a `nodesToVisit` queue and so on.

Consider the following code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var nodesToVisit = [{id:1, children:[2,3]}]; // 1 is the root

Promise.each(nodesToVisit, val => {
    console.log(val.id);
    if(val.children) {
       val.children.forEach(child => {
         var getChildFromDatabasePromise = myDatabase.get(child); 
         nodesToVisit.push(getChildFromDatabasePromise);
       });
    }
});
```

This does not work because `Promise.each` will be done before pushing the `getChildFromDatabasePromise` to it.

I guess the core of the question is how to make a dynamic while loop using promises?

Comment: Why not simply `Promise.each(val.children, …)`? You seem to know that method already.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The children might have children of their own, so I'll need to visit them but I can't append the promise of visiting them to the `nodesToVisit`.

Comment: If children have nested children, you'll want to use recursion. And yes, waiting for a promise before appending the result to your array is exactly what you will need to do.

Comment: What does tree-traversal have to do with a graph?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 a tree is a graph, I just thought about a "simpler" version. A promise-based solution to graph traversal where getting a node's neighbour is asynchronous would be the ultimate goal.

Comment: When I was at school, 
tree == [tree](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tree+diagram&tbm=isch) and 
graph == [graph](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=graph&tbm=isch), but maybe they teach everything different these days.

Comment: A [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) is a special case of a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) where vertices are connected by exactly one path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about wrapping your code in a function and calling it recursively?

```
var nodesToVisit = [{id:1, children:[2,3]}]; // 1 is the root

visitNextBatch();

function visitNextBatch() {
    var copyOfNodes = nodesToVisit;
    nodesToVisit = [];
    Promise.each(copyOfNodes, val => {
        console.log(val.id);
        if(val.children) {
            val.children.forEach(child => {
            var getChildFromDatabasePromise = myDatabase.get(child); 
            nodesToVisit.push(getChildFromDatabasePromise);
           });
        }
    }).then(function() {
        visitNextBatch();
    })
}
```